# RAM memory mapping - Need clarification

Tags: windows-ce

Total RAM size is `512 MB`.

On my WEC7 device control panel, I'm seeing total memory as:

```
Storage memory: 53792 KB
Program memory: 376140 KB
```

So, total size is : `419MB`.

My `config.bib` has following:

```
SECTION_BASE     80000000      00001000     RESERVED
ARGS             80001000      00001000     RESERVED
RSVD             80002000      001BA000     RESERVED
EMAC             801BC000      00009000     RESERVED 
RSVD1            801C5000      0003B000     RESERVED
FBUFFER          95B00000      00200000     RESERVED 

#define NK_START    80200000
#define NK_SIZE     05E00000
#define RAM_START   86000000 
#define RAM_SIZE    0FB00000
```

According to this, `RAM_SIZE` is `251MB`.

AFAIK, this is `Program memory + Storage memory`. Is my understanding is correct? If yes, why this difference? If no, what is the correct explanation for this?

My `image_cfg.h` has following line:

```
#define STATIC_MAPPING_RAM_SIZE             (384)
```

And `oemaddrtab_cfg.inc` file has:

```
g_oalAddressTable

DCD 0x80000000, 0x00100000, STATIC_MAPPING_RAM_SIZE   ; RAM image mapping; 0x80000000+384MB=0x98000000
DCD 0x9B000000, 0xFC000000, 64                        ; 64 MB Peripheral device space (As per  datasheet)
DCD 0x9F100000, 0x00000000, 1                         ;Mapping Boot region
DCD 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0                         ; Terminate table
```

NK size:

```
nk.bin: 51MB
nk.nb0: 94MB
```

Anybody please explain why I am getting `419MB` of memory, and also please explain more about these memory mapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the amount you specify in the config file you can have an additional RAM region passed to the system through the OEMGetExtendedDRAM function in your OAL. For BSPs supporting devices with different amounts of RAM is common to have the minimum amount configured in the bib file, detect if additional RAM is available, and return it using the above function.

Comment: Hi @Valter, I checked in my OAL code, I am not seeing `OEMGetExtendedDRAM` function. But in function `OEMGetRamTable`, I'm seeing this line: `g_RamTableEntry[0].RamSize = (512 - STATIC_MAPPING_RAM_SIZE) * 1024 * 1024;` What is the significance of this? And, why I don't have function `OEMGetExtendedDRAM`?

Comment: If your BSP uses the common code under PLATFORM\COMMON\SRC\COMMON the OEMGetExtendedDRAM function is implemented there and references some globals vars or other functions in your OAL. You can look at the sources file under OALexe to understand which parts of the common implementation are used by your BSP. There are also SOC-specific implementations that may use the same technique. Best option is to search where that var is used in the PLATFORM\COMMON folder